# What software can I use to build a recommendation engine with data access via REST?

Tags: open-source, software-development, rest, recommendation-engine

The data is stored in a database to which a RESTful access can be provided.

Can I build a recommendation engine over a subset of the data from database? I don't want to store data from the database locally.

What software can be used to fulfill the above?

Comment: As its name suggests, Software Recommendations is for questions asking for recommendations of software ready-to-use to accomplish a particular task, that is, “what software can I use to do …?” Can you fit your question into this format?

Comment: Hi Karel, thanks for the recommendation, Ive reframed the question. I am learning to frame the question right as I am new here.

Comment: Look into Ajax & then go with either  JS and Node,Js on the server, or JS and PHP on the server. For JS, I prefer AngularJs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) to create a .NET application, using [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) as a library for accessing the data.

Both, MonoDevelop and RestSharp are OpenSource.